# C# - Capture spacebar press during console application execution

Tags: c#, console-application, capture, keyboard-events

Is there a way to run a process in a console application, and during the execution, if the space bar is pressed, update the console with the status of the application?  We have a process that parses files for formatting, and during execution, the status is not updated. Is there a way to capture the keyboard event during execution similar to the CTRL-C delegate approach?

TL/DR: During a running process, use the spacebar to update the screen with status.

C# Console application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well sure, but you'll need a background thread for the actual processing. Basically, just have your console process kick off your file parsing in a background thread, then while it's working, loop through a check for a keypress and a Thread.Yield() statement. If a key was pressed, get a status update from some class the background thread is updating as it works:

```
private static StatusObject Status;

public static void main(params string[] args)
{
   var thread = new Thread(PerformProcessing);
   Status = new StatusObject();
   thread.Start(Status);

   while(thread.IsAlive)
   {
      if(keyAvailable)
         if(Console.ReadKey() == ' ')
            ShowStatus(Status);

      //This is necessary to ensure that this main thread doesn't monopolize
      //the CPU going through this loop; let the background thread work a while
      Thread.Yield();
   }

   thread.Join();
}

public void PerformProcessing(StatusObject status)
{
   //do your file parsing, and at significant stages of the process (files, lines, etc)
   //update the StatusObject with vital info. You will need to obtain a lock.
}

public static void ShowStatus(StatusObject status)
{
   //lock the StatusObject, get the information from it, and show it in the console.
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I will have to learn more about how threading works, but this is a good start.  Again, thanks for the help.